# How to get Columns in DataGridViewRowSelectedRowCollection

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridviewcolumn

Ok guys, I thought this would be easier than it is.

```
 public static DataRowCollection ToRows(this DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection Rows)
 {
     DataTable table = new DataTable();            

     foreach (DataColumn column in Rows[0].DataGridView.Columns)
     {
         table.Columns.Add(column);
     }

     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in Rows)
     {
         DataRow newRow = ((DataRowView)row.DataBoundItem).Row;
         table.ImportRow(newRow);
     }

     return table.Rows;
}
```

I'm trying to get the columns of a row in a DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection.  The code above throws an InvalidCast error on the table.Columns.Add(column) because it is trying to cast DataGridViewColumns to DataTable columns.  I dont have access to the DataGridView because I am in a static method that Extends the DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection and do not have access to the DataGridView.

How can I cast the columns collection to a DataColumns object?

Comment: If you say what's the data source of `DataGridView` and why do you need to create such data table on the fly, maybe a better solution can be proposed.

Comment: As you can see, the method is static and is an extension.  I have several grids that will need to be able to get the selected rows in a grid and return the rows to the calling update method.  I could just do this in the calling method, but then every time I want to do this, I have to copy the same code, which means every time I update the code in one place, it has to be updated everywhere else.

Comment: Are all grids bound to DataTables? Is the goal getting selected data rows from a grid?

Comment: Yes DataTables, and Yes Selected Rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an extension method to return the data rows behind selected rows of grid this way:

```
public static class DataGridViewExtensions
{
    public static List<DataRow> ToDataRows(this DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection Rows)
    {
        if (Rows == null || Rows.Count == 0)
            return null;

        return Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
                   .Where(x => x.DataBoundItem is DataRowView)
                   .Select(x => ((DataRowView)(x.DataBoundItem)).Row).ToList();
    }
}
```

Then to get values from a `row` variable of type `DataRow`, consider using these options:

- `row.ItemArray` contains all column values
- `row[index]` gets the value of a column by index
- `row["column name"]` gets the value of column by column name
- `row.Table.Columns` contains a list of columns of `DataTable`

Comment: I still have to have the columns later on so this is close, but not what I'm looking for.

Comment: What's the problem? it seems you were trying to get selected datarows as you also mentioned in comments.

Comment: Using data entities to delete records. Even if I get a List<DataRow? back, the TableAdapter.Delete method requires passing in all columns in a row as parameters and, so I would need to be able to access the columns in each DataRow to do that.

Comment: So it seem to be an [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem. Currently the post answers your question based  on your comment as you said *Yes DataTables, and Yes Selected Rows*. In response of my question *Are all grids bound to DataTables? Is the goal getting selected data rows from a grid? * But it seems you have another requirement.

Comment: I'm interested to hear about your main requirement (the main reason which made you ask this question) and try to satisfy it. So I recommend you to ask a new question describing your main requirement, because currently I strongly believe the post answers your question.

Comment: Your code solution works so long as I am ok with a list of DataRows but assumes I have no interest in the columns of the rows which is not the case.  I have an interest in the columns but cannot find a way to access them in either your or my solutions. If I have access to the columns in the list, then I should have them where I want them, in my extension code where I want to use them.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't what you mean, because getting columns from a `DataRow` is not a big deal. `row.ItemArray` contains all column values, also `row[index]` or `row["name"]` gets the value of a single column. Also `row.Table.Columns` contains a list of columns.

Comment: Could you use any of those properties which I mentioned?

Comment: Good for you! and Good to hear that it solved at last! You know, you should ask questions about your actual requirement. When you ask only about the problem of your solution, usually the answer you get is not what you expected. Remember the previous question which you asked. I commented the value should be null and how can you expect a value different than null. It was not a bad answer or sarcasm at all (while I removed it to prevent from misunderstanding) You should ask about the requirement, also share your effort, then the one who answers may solve the problem or maybe offer a new solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117324/discussion-between-d-j-and-reza-aghaei).

Comment: Thanks for feedback.  I re-read comments and see where I misunderstood your question.  The goal was to get the columns of the datarows of the DataGridViewSelectedRows property.  Bigger goal was to be able to return a DataRows collection from a static method hence the name ToRows() but you cant just copy the rows because it complains that the row or column being copied already belongs to a datatable.

Comment: You're welcome :) By the way, when you accept an answer, it would be great if you also upvote the answer :)

Comment: Sorry.  I thought I did!  :)